# Spark Anomaly Detection Multivariate Gaussian Threshold

Tags: apache-spark, anomaly-detection

I have a dataset on which I will use Apache Spark for Anomaly Detection. I have computed the Probability Distribution Function using Spark ML and I would like next to identify outliers given their probability. How do I pick the epsilon(threshold) for the distribution?